# Right code of comparing two objects in pure/native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison, compare

What is the right code in pure/native JavaScript, if the data 1 and data 2 are both different, there will be 2 new tab will open? But if the data 1 and data 2 have same value, there's only 1 new tab will open? I have a script of comparing the values of data 1 and data 2, but I don't know how to do the right and proper code of comparing 2 objects. I read articles and questions here in stackoverflow. But still I don't understand how to do that.

E.g. When the values of data 1 is the same of values in data 2, there's an confirmation box will pop up and open new tab.
But when data 1 and 2 are both different values there's a two confirmation box will pop up, first is for data 1 and open new tab. Second, for data 2 and open new tab again (for data 2)

Please help me. I'm a newbie in JavaScript. Thank you

[Here's the link of complete updated code of comparing values and open new tab](http://jsfiddle.net/zCQtN/)

```
            // When both addresses have same values
            if (data 1=== data 2) {
                if (confirm("Do you want to proceed on Google Maps and search for Contact Address?") == true) {
                    gmaps = tabCreate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(response.data.data1));
                } else {
                    gmaps = "";
                }
            }
            // When both addresses have different values
            if (data1!= data2) {
                if (confirm("Do you want to proceed on Google Maps and search for Permanent Address?") == true) {
                    gmaps = tabCreate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(response.data.data2));
                } else {
                    gmaps = "";
                }
            }
```

[Here's the code link of two data 1 and 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7Cq/)

Comment: You seem to have a custom *getElement* function that you haven't shown or indicated what the return value is. It might be an Array, a NodeList or Object. What is, say, *eltr*?

Comment: @RobG eltr means element of table row

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
function scanLapVerification() {
try {
```

*try* with no *catch* indicates that at least there is no point in the *try*. Remove it.

```
    //check if the page is activity where address check is done
    var page_title = "Prelim checks - CB BAP";
    var el = getElement(document, "class", "view-operator-verification-title", "");
```

What does *getElement* do? What does it return?

```
    if (!el || el.length == 0) return;
    if (el[0].innerText != page_title) return;
    var page_title = '';
```

*page_title* is used once, the its value is changed and it's not used again. The line above doesn't seem to do anything useful.

```
    var el = getElement(document, "class", "workflowActivityDetailPanel", "");
    if (el && el.length > 0) {
```

Without knowing what *getElement* returns, or how it works, it's impossible to tell if that test is suitable or not.

```
    var eltr = getElement(el[0], "tag", "tr", "");
```

I'll guess that *eltr* is an Array of *tr* elements (I might be wrong though…).

```
    if (eltr && eltr.length > 0) {
            //Read Contact and Permanent address
            var addresses = {
                D1: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, snumber: null }
               ,D2: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, bnumber: null }
            };
            var address_type = null;
```

There is rarely a need to initialise a variable to *null*, they are initialised to *undefined* by default which suits most purposes.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < eltr.length; i++) {
                tr_text = eltr[i].innerText;
```

Not all browsers support *innerText*, you may need a function with some feature detection that uses *textContent* or *innerText* depending on which is supported.

```
                if (tr_text.substr(0, "Data 1".length) == "Data 1") address_type = "D1";
                if (tr_text.substr(0, "Data 2".length) == "Data 2") address_type = "D2";
```

That can be:

```
    if (/^Data 1/.test(tr_text)) address_type = 'D1';
    if (/^Data 2/.test(tr_text)) address_type = 'D2';
```

.

```
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Province".length) == "Province") {
                    addresses[address_type].province = tr_text.substr("Province".length + 1, tr_text.length - "Province".length - 1);
```

That can be:

```
  if (address_type && /^Province/.test(tr_text) {
    addresses[address_type].province = tr_text.replace(/^Province/,'');
  }
```

and so on.

```
[...]
        //Comparing of two objects
        var data1 = addresses.D1.street
                            + '' + addresses.D1.barangay 
                            + '' + addresses.D1.province
                            + '' + addresses.D1.zip;
        data1 = data1 .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();

        var permanent_address = data1 ;

        alert(data1 === data2); //true
        alert(data1 != data2); //false

        return { content: "address_check", data1 : data1 , data2: data2};
```

It seems you want to compare two objects to see if they have the same own properties and same–named properties have the same values. Something like the following may suit:

```
function haveSamePropsAndValues(a, b) {

  // Get the own properties of each object
  var aKeys = Object.keys(a);
  var bKeys = Object.keys(b);

  // Compare properties and values
  // If different number of properties, not the same
  if (aKeys.length != bKeys.length) return false;

  // If have same number of properties, compare their names and values
  for (var i=0, iLen=aKeys.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Check property names
    if (aKeys[i] != bKeys[i]) return false;

    // Check property values
    if (a[aKeys[i]] != b[bKeys[i]]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The above function returns true if the two objects have the same number of properties with the same names and same values. Otherwise it returns false. It only checks own properties, not inherited. Note that it will return true for two empty objects too.

This only works if the values being compared are identical, so you might want to trim leading and trailing white space and reduce any internal whitespace to single. Also perhaps convert to lower case before comparing so that `' Fred ' == 'fred'` returns true.

A very quick and dirty version is:

```
function haveSamePropsAndValues(a, b){
  return JSON.stringify(a).toLowerCase() == JSON.stringify(b).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: See. But how to do if the two object is different, it will open 2 new tab while if the two object is same, it will open 1 new tab only? Please see, my second code displayed

Comment: I try to apply the code that you give in comparing two objects but seems its not working

Comment: The above compares the properties and values of two objects, how you apply that to opening or closing tabs is unrelated.

Comment: I tried to change the akeys and bkeys to the original object name in my code and tried to connect it into my existing function, that posted above

Comment: @Ying—So where you have `if (contact_address === permanent_address) {...}` you need something like `if (haveSamePropsAndValues(contact_address, permanent_address)) {...}`. There is no need for a second test, just use an else since they are either the same or they aren't, use something like `if(same){/*do a*/}else{/*do b*/}`.